# Need - fast exhaustive memory testing tool for Dell server

Tags: testing

I've got a Dell 2950 running ESXi.  I'm having weird issues in one of the VMs and I would like to do a memory test to eliminate (or identify) faulty RAM as the problem.

What is the easiest/fastest tool for me to use to do an exhaustive test of the system memory?

It would be nice if the tool came as a bootable CD/DVD image so I can shut down my server, boot from CD/DVD, do the test, then boot as usual when it's complete.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

memtest.org is exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

If you still have the diagnostics boot partition that Dell installs at the factory up you can just boot into it and run the memory tests.

Dell might also have a bootable ISO image. I'm checking for that now and will posted an update if found.

Answer (score 1):

You can download and burn the [System rescue CD](http://www.sysresccd.org/Main_Page) and run memtest off of it.  It will take a while, but it will be exhaustive.

Answer (score 0):

I really like the windiag memory test from Microsoft.  It runs off of a bootable CDRom.  I have seen this test running in the Advanced mode (press T when it starts) find memory problems that other tests have missed.
http://oca.microsoft.com/en/windiag.asp

EDIT:  Having said that - advanced mode is not particularly fast.  It runs through 11 exhaustive tests, so it may take an hour or considerably more depending on how much memory is in the system.